# Android BiometricPrompt Compat library

Tags: android, fingerprint, biometrics, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

Hi as mention in [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/better-biometrics-in-android-p.html) post there is **BiometricPrompt API** for devices supporting Android O and lower but I am unable to find out **BiometricPrompt Compat Library** (as mention in image), is anyone able to help me to point out where is that support library, any link or guide?[image]

Comment: I suspect that it does not exist yet. It does not appear in the JavaDocs. I cannot find a particular support library that seems to have biometrics (or even security in general) as a focus.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question, I hope Google take note. I've been unable to find it in support 28.0.0-rc01 or any other mentions elsewhere.

Comment: I've the same thought when I read that, this question is helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming it will be released soon as the source code for it appears here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/biometric/src/main/java/androidx/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.java.

I'm guessing the Google Maven artifact will be androidx.biometrics. (See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx)

Comment: If anybody wants to know how to use Biometric Compact APIs following is a good article   
https://medium.com/@natiginfo/fingerprint-authentication-using-biometricprompt-compat-1466365b4795

Comment: The Maven artifact (and its latest version) can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.biometric/biometric

Comment: This answer do not help at all .. i always have stupid errors when adding bio-metric support libraries .. please see question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052336/cant-add-androidx-biometric-dependency-to-app-level-build-gradle-file/55052566#55052566 My simple question is how can i add this into my cordova-android project ?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed in the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx repository.

You can find it here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.biometric

Comment: This answer do not help at all .. i always have stupid errors when adding bio-metric support libraries .. please see question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052336/cant-add-androidx-biometric-dependency-to-app-level-build-gradle-file/55052566#55052566