# Could not find support library for BiometricPrompt

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, biometrics

I Could not find the support library for BiometricPrompt to support older API levels. But they mentioned there will be androidX support library. I could not find any...

Comment: This question is already asked, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558350/android-biometricprompt-compat-library/51813617#51813617

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric) of the **Androidx Biometric** library.

Currently just add this dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha04'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find BiometricPrompt support library [here](https://github.com/fython/BiometricPromptCompat)

Comment: Actually, that is a third party compat library. But I was searching for official compat library from android.